# WooCommerce: exclude sale price based on user role

Tags: woocommerce

I'm using [WooCommerce](http://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/) and the [Dynamic Pricing extension](http://www.woothemes.com/products/dynamic-pricing/). I've set pricing discounts for 2 user roles (Dealers and Distributors) with the extension. Currently, if I set a sale price on a product, the sale price is reflected for all user roles, and the extension discount for Dealers and Distributors is then compounded on top of it.

How would I conditionally state that if the user is a Dealer or Distributor, remove the sale price but still apply the price discount that's set in Dynamic Pricing?